# Decomposition of hermitian matrix as difference of positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite, hermitian-matrices, quantum-information

In my reference, [Box 11.2, Page 512, Chapter 11, Entropy and Information, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf), proof of the Fannes' inequality contains

[image: p1]

here $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are positive semidefinite(hermitian with nonzero eigenvalues) with eigenvalues lies in the interval $[0,1]$(constitute a probability distribution).

In another document, [Theorem 10.2, Lecture 10: Continuity of von Neumann entropy;
quantum relative entropy, John Watrous' Lecture notes](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI-notes/TQI-notes.10.pdf), it is given that

[image: p2]

> How can we prove that any hermitian operator can be decomposed in terms of the difference between two positive semidefinite operators?

---

Here, $A=VD_AV^\dagger$ and $B=UD_BU^\dagger$ need not commute (not simultaneously diagonalized).

The difference between two hermitian matrices is hermitian, ie., $H=A-B$ is hermitian.

$H=A-B=WD_HW^\dagger$, and we are free to choose diagonal matrices $D_p$ and $D_q$ such that $D_H=D_p-D_q$, i.e., $H=WD_HW^\dagger=W(D_p-D_q)W^\dagger=WD_pW^\dagger-WD_qW^\dagger=P-Q$

It would be helpful if one could point in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, your observation quite correct, except the last equality (probably a typo).

Comment: To ensure that $P$ and $Q$ are orthogonal, make sure to choose $D_p$ and $D_q$ to be positive semidefinite. Essentially, $D_p$ has all of the positive eigenvalues of $H$ and $D_q$ contains the negation of all the negative eigenvalues of $H$. This ensures that $D_p$ and $D_q$ have orthogonal supports, so that $D_pD_q = D_qD_p = 0$. (And thus $PQ=QP=0$.)

Comment: @glS other document is "John Watrous' Lecture notes", and I have edited the post by adding the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\rho - \sigma$ is Hermitian, you can diagonalize it and all its eigenvalues fall between $[-2,2]$ by the triangle inequality. Let $Q$ be the diagonal matrix whose eigenvalues are exactly the non-negative eigenvalues of $\rho - \sigma$ and let $R$ be the diagonal matrix whose eigenvalues are the negatives of the negative eigenvalues of $\rho - \sigma$. So, both $Q$ and $R$ are positive and if you've ordered the eigenvalues right, $Q-R = \rho-\sigma$ after a suitable unitary change of basis. Note that $Q$ and $R$ will have orthogonal support since $Q$ only supports the positive eigenspace and $R$ only supports the negative eigenspace, and these are obviously orthogonal (no eigenvalue is both negative and positive).

Comment: How can the sum of two diagonal matrices equal a possibly nondiagonal matrix?

Comment: You must first diagonalize $\rho-\sigma$ by choosing a diagonalizing unitary $U$ such that $H=U(\rho-\sigma)U^\dagger$ is diagonal. Then you can take $\rho-\sigma = U^\dagger Q U - U^\dagger R U$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a generic Hermitian operator. Given an orthonormal basis for the space made with its eigenvectors, and the associated eigenvalues, we can always decompose it as
$$A = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k P_k$$
where $P_k\equiv |u_k\rangle\!\langle u_k|$ and $|u_k\rangle$ is the eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_k$. Because $A$ is Hermitian we have $\lambda_k\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now just consider the terms in this decomposition corresponding to positive and negative eigenvalues.
There will be some subsets of $[n]\equiv \{1,..., n\}$, written with $S_\pm$, containing the indices associated to positive and negative eigenvalues, respectively. Thus
$$A = \underbrace{\sum_{k\in S_+} \lambda_k P_k}_{\equiv A_+} + \underbrace{\sum_{k\in S_-} \lambda_k P_k}_{\equiv -A_-}.$$
Here I just defined $A_\pm$ to equal the two terms in the equation as written.
The operator $A_+$ is clearly positive semidefinite, as it's Hermitian with non-negative eigenvalues. But $A_-$ is positive semidefinite for the same reason, considering that $\lambda_k<0$ for $k\in S_-$. It follows that $A=A_+-A_-$ with $A_\pm \ge 0$.